# Storing array of images in CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, core-data

I am trying to store array of images in CoreData. I know that the best way is to store images in app's directory and store links to them in CD, but I don't want to completely reorganise my app and keep storing the binary data in CD.

I've figured out how to store single image:
In xcdatamodeld I've created `thumbnailImageData` of binary type.
In my .h I show it as UIImage type:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) UIImage* thumbnailImage;
```

and in .m I've declared `thumbanilImageData` and set `thumbnailImage` as dynamic and reformated thumbnailImage to binary in getter and setter:

```
@implementation galleryItem {
    NSData* thumbnailImageData;
}

@dynamic thumbnailImage;

-(UIImage *)thumbnailImage {
    UIImage* returnThumbnailImage = [UIImage imageWithData:thumbnailImageData];
    return returnThumbnailImage;
}

- (void)setThumbnailImage:(UIImage *)thumbnailImage {
    thumbnailImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnailImage);
}
```

How can I do the same thing to store/set/get array of images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already abusing CoreData, so why not abuse it further: use `NSCoding`!

```
-(NSArray *)thumbnailImages {
    NSMutableArray* images = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSArray* imageDatas = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:self.thumbnailImagesData];
    for (NSData* imageData in imageDatas) {
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
    }
    return images;
}

- (void)setThumbnailImages:(NSArray *)thumbnailImages {
    NSMutableArray* thumbnailImageDatas = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (UIImage* image in thumbnailImages) {
        [thumbnailImageDatas addObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(resizedImage)];
    }
    self.thumbnailImagesData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:thumbnailImageDatas];
}
```

Where `self.thumbnailImagesData` is an `NSData` property managed by CoreData.

Comment: Worked like a charm! thanks. Not elegant solution (as requested), but works.